# how to remove accessory from cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i have the indexPath number... i need to remove the cell accessory from that cell based on the number in the variable i have?

```
NSInteger *removeAccessoryFrom = 3;

                    [studentTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:removeAccessoryFrom].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like that. You need to reload the table data (either for the whole table or for just this row) and, inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, set the accessoryType to `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone` *conditionally*. In other words, you keep a list, or have some other way of knowing, *at every moment*, and *for the entire table*, exactly what cells get exactly what accessory. That way, *any* time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called, you can configure this cell for this index path correctly.

Comment: Yep, one can use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` rather that just `reloadData`, but either way the cell must be reloaded, with the change made inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @HotLicks Good point, though - I've added a phrase to cover that.